# Error returning string haskell

Tags: string, haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to merge a string in Haskell, however I got the following error,I think the problem is in the function returns fristElem, lastElem merges, but do not know fix the error, how can I fix the error?

```
MasterMind.hs:79:98:
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’
            with actual type ‘[t0] -> [t0]’
Probable cause: ‘fristElem’ is applied to too few arguments
In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
  ‘fristElem (compareShot attempt attempt psw)’
In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
  ‘"\tSeu palpite gero a seguinte dica -> "
   ++ fristElem (compareShot attempt attempt psw)’
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

**Code used**

```
compareShot [] _ _ = ""
compareShot (a:attempt) attemptAux psw
    |elemIndex a psw == elemIndex a attemptAux = "P" ++ compareShot attempt attemptAux psw
    |elemIndex a psw == Nothing = "V" ++ compareShot attempt attemptAux psw
    |otherwise = "B" ++ compareShot attempt attemptAux psw


fristElem 0 _ = []
fristElem n (a:xs) = a : fristElem (n-1) xs

lastElem 1 (a:xs) = xs
lastElem n (a:xs) = lastElem (n-1) xs

intercala [] [] = []
intercala (a:xf) (b:xl) = (b:(a:intercala xf xl))`


{-Conta quantas vezes o usuario realizou as tentativas e trata to o fluxo de acerto ou erro-}
attempts :: (Num i, Eq i, Show i) => i -> String -> IO ()
attempts 0 _ = putStrLn "Game Over... !"
attempts i psw = do
    putStrLn $ "Entre com o seu palpite ("++ (show i) ++"): (Os digitos do seu palpite devem ser unicos e estar entre 1000 e 9876)"
    attempt <- getLine
    if validateShot attempt then
        if attempt == psw
            then putStrLn $ (show attempt) ++ "\nParabens você ganho!"
        else do
            putStrLn $ (show attempt) ++ "\tSeu palpite gero a seguinte dica -> " ++            fristElem(compareShot attempt attempt psw)
            attempts (i-1) psw
    else do
        putStrLn $ (show attempt) ++ "- Palpite não é valido!"
        attempts (i-1) psw
```

Comment: The error message says `fristElem` (strange name) takes two arguments, but gets only one. This is also clear from your code: the first argument is a number (it's precise type is hard to say since you omit signatures), and the second is a list. At the call site, you only pass the result of `compareShot attempt attempt psw` to `fristElem`.

Comment: Also, please try to reduce your code to a minimum example illustrating the problem. There's way too much stuff going on described in a language (Portuguese?) that most people on SO don't understand.

Comment: Is this an attempt to write [Mastermind (board game)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29)? Anyway, once you fix the compile error, get over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to learn more

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `fristElem` and `lastElem` instead of `take` and `drop`? Those are standard functions, and work better. By the way, I think 'guess' is a better translation for 'palpite' than 'attempt' or 'shot', mas não falo portugues :-)

Comment: But anyway, welcome to SO, and nice to see someone from USP-SC here; in a slightly different universe I could have done a PhD there (but Haskell was very unknown there, 3 years ago).

Comment: Yes, i'm not using take and drop because my function get the nth elements

Comment: Try removing the other functions, and see what happens when you enter `fristElem 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `lastElem 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6]` in ghci, or find out their types via ':t fristElem'. You will be surprised!